# Weird Xerces method access error

Tags: java, spring, xerces, oc4j

I've tried this on both Xerces 2.9.1, and Xerces-J-2.11.0 with the same results.

I'm writing a Spring3 Webflow app, using Xerces for XML parsing. When deploying the EAR, I get an issue

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Lorg/apache/xerces/jaxp/DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl;Ljava/util/Hashtable;Ljava/util/Hashtable;)V from class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 30 more
```

If I trace the code in a Java Decompilor, in `xercesImpl.jar`I can see the `DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setAttribute()` call tries to create a new `DocumentBuilderImpl`, this seems to be the cause of the `IllegalAccessError`. The constructor for the `DocumentBuilderImpl` has default (package) access, but both `DocumentBuilderImpl`, and `DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl` reside in the same package (`org.apache.xerces.jaxp`).

As far as I'm aware, there is no `SecurityManager` active at the time of the error (and I'm not even sure whether the `SecurityManager` would affect method access permissions, I thought it was just for class loading, and resource access permissions).

Any ideas what I can do (short of recompiling the xerces JAR with less restrictive access permissions, I'd like to sort out the root of the problem, not work around it!, I'd also prefer to use the standard JARs where I can).

I should mention, I'm using Spring 3.0.5, OC4J 10.0.3.5.0 (with the work-around in place to use the Xerces XML parser instead of the Oracle XML parser), and Java 1.6.0-21.

Thanks
Graham

Comment: Who favorited this? I barely had the question up and it was marked as favorite. Just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having a class-loader issue because you're bundling Xerxes; and Java 1.6 already bundles Xerces.

I've had many "unexpected" problems with xerces, activation, and a few other libraries that we external before java 1.6 and are now bundled in the JRE. :(

Comment: So, I shouldn't bundle the JAR files at all? I'll try this out. Thanks.

Comment: yes, remove them from your application. Unfortunately, I haven't found a list of the libraries which are now bundled in java, and shouldn't be added :(.

Comment: Thanks, I tried removing all references to the xerces JARs and it seems to work now.